# Tamanho de pixel de uma String em Python

Tags: python, string, pixels, reportlab

Gostaria de saber como fazer um código em Python que verifica o tamanho de uma string (em pixels).

Suposição: temos uma string 'ALCON BOTTON FISH 50G' gostaria de saber qual seu tamanho em pixel para centralizar em um quadrado que estou plotando com reportlab (estou usando plotagem absoluta - informando a posição x e y - por não encontrar um jeito automático de fazer essa centralização)

Comment: Se a fonte for  `monospace` talvez consiga, se não for vai ficar complicado.

Comment: Ficou meio confusa sua pergunta, "tamanho de um pixel"? o tamanho de um pixel vai depender da resolução e/ou do dispositivo que esta sendo apresentado a imagem, não importa se a imagem representa uma string ou um passaro, a mesma string que vc da como exemplo pode ser "construida"  e/ou plotada em diferentes resolucoes (pixels por polegadas), esqueça a string representada na imagem e foque nas caracteristica da imagem (tamanho, resolução, etc)

Comment: Algumas tecnologias, como a Qt, tem este recurso, mas só faz sentido isso usando as mesmas funções de quem vai plotar/desenhar o texto em definitivo. Tem que ver se o tal reportlab tem função adequada para isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe um cálculo único, pois o tamanho resultante Depende da fonte. Em Arial 12 é um tamanho, em Times New Roman 12 vai dar outro... se usar negrito, muda também.

Ainda existe o Kerning, que é a diferença no espaçamento entre duas letras, dependendo de quais letras são:

[image: kerning]

Portanto fica difícil calcular isso sem desenhar a fonte. Um exemplo, no `Pillow` tem a função `ImageFont.getsize()`:

```
>>> arial = PIL.ImageFont.truetype('Arial', 12)
>>> arial.getsize('Palavra')
(42, 11)
```